# Is there a way to get the original source, including whitespace, from inside a proc macro?

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I'm working on a DSL implemented as a proc macro, and would like to be able to get to the original source, as a string, of the contents of the proc macro.

So for instance, if my proc macro is invoked like so:

```
my_macro! {
one
two
three
}
```

I would like to get access to this string inside the proc macro implementation:

```
let source: String = get_source(input) // this is what I want to be able to do

println!("{}", source);
// prints: "one\ntwo\nthree"
```

I can't figure out how to do this.  When I try to convert the token stream to a string, the whitespace information is lost.

So for instance if I try to convert the token stream directly to a string, each token is simply separated by a space:

```
#[proc_macro]
pub fn my_macro(input: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream {
    
    println!("{}", input);
    // prints "one two three"

...
```

How can I get the input source?

Comment: You could use the unstable methods `start` and `end` on `Span` to get the line and column number. That would allow you to recover whitespace. I've seen this used once for parsing whitespace sensitive languages or sth like that.

Comment: You might want to [edit] your question to add your use case. This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It's not an XY problem I can assure you.  I gave a concrete example.